# Issues with Indexing and Merging XTS Objects in R

Tags: r, merge, indexing, xts, zoo

Apologies in advance if this is answered elsewhere. I have searched for roughly 24 hrs and have come up empty at every turn.

[This](https://quantquote.com/sample/SPY_MINUTE_TRADE.csv) is the data set I am working with

```
Sys.setenv(TZ='GMT')
dat = read.csv("SPY_MINUTE_TRADE.csv", header = TRUE) #QuantQuote sample minute data
dat[,2] <- sprintf('%04d', dat[,2]) #add a zero to front of time IE 400 becomes 0400 aka 4AM

#Create a zoo object ordered by day and time from the dat dataframe
datzoo <- read.zoo(file=dat, sep=",", header=TRUE, 
                 index.column=1:2, format="%Y%m%d %H%M", tz="", 
                 colClasses = rep(c("character", "numeric"), c(2, 8)))

Spy <- as.xts(datzoo)

# Create regular series from 00:00 to 23:59 of 1 minute prints
y <-  xts(seq(from = 1, to = 60*24, by = 1), as.POSIXlt((0), 
    origin="2013-03-30 00:00", tz='GMT')+seq(from = 0, to = 60*60*24-1, by = 60))
colnames(y) <- "TempIndex"

#Merge the regular ts (y) with Spy and remove the original Spy column
SpyReg <- merge(y,Spy, join='left')
SpyReg$TempIndex <- NULL

#Capture the index of Spy
ISpy <- index(Spy)
```

I have a few questions about the above code...

1) `SpyReg["2012-03-30 04:00:00 GMT"]` returns

```
 OPEN HIGH LOW CLOSE VOLUME SPLITS EARNINGS DIVIDENDS
```

`Spy["2012-03-30 04:00:00 GMT"]` returns the correct values of Spy for the given index

```
                      OPEN   HIGH    LOW  CLOSE VOLUME SPLITS EARNINGS DIVIDENDS
2012-03-30 04:00:00 140.66 140.66 140.66 140.66   2160      1        0         0
```

However,

```
SpyReg["T04:00:00/T04:01:00"]
                    OPEN HIGH LOW CLOSE VOLUME SPLITS EARNINGS DIVIDENDS
2013-03-30 04:00:00   NA   NA  NA    NA     NA     NA       NA        NA
2013-03-30 04:01:00   NA   NA  NA    NA     NA     NA       NA        NA
```

why is this, when both are xts objects of the same index type, month, and time? Shouldn't `SpyReg[""2012-03-30 04:00:00 GMT"]` return:

```
                    OPEN HIGH LOW CLOSE VOLUME SPLITS EARNINGS DIVIDENDS
2013-03-30 04:00:00   NA   NA  NA    NA     NA     NA       NA        NA
```

2) Why did the merge not give `SpyReg` the `Spy` value for the same index (such as the 4AM print?) I tried all 4 "join" options, but none worked...

3) I assume there is a MUCH more elegant way to solve this problem than what I am trying to do. After creating `Spy`, it was not regular, minute by minute. I wanted to create a regular `xts` object that had no gaps and flowed continuously minute by minute from midnight to 23:59, add the entries from `Spy` into it, then do a `na.locf` to replace the rest of the `NAs` with the original data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the index of an xts object to `POSIXlt` can cause some strange behaviors.  I'd simply recommend you use `POSIXct` instead.

```
URL <- "http://quantquote.com/sample/SPY_MINUTE_TRADE.csv"
Spy <- read.zoo(URL, sep=",", header=TRUE, index.column=1:2, FUN=function(x) 
    as.POSIXct(sprintf("%8d %04d",x[,1],x[,2]), format="%Y%m%d %H%M", tz=""))
Spy <- as.xts(Spy)
```

Now you can merge `Spy` with an 'empty' xts object that has the regular index values you want.

```
SpyReg <- merge(Spy, xts(, seq(start(Spy),end(Spy),by="1 min")), fill=na.locf)
```

Comment: A) That was infinitely more elegant so thank you.

B) In your solution, SpyReg['T04:00:00'] only returns the header. SpyReg['T04:00:00/T04:00:01'] returned the entry for 4AM. I feel I am misusing xts on a basic level and was wondering if you could point out my error?

C) You said I should use "ct" instead of "lt"... I reran my original code, but in the step where I create "y", I used POSIXct rather than lt, and it still gave me all of the merging headaches....

Thanks as always, Your help is absolutely invaluable sir!

Comment: A) You're welcome. B) "time-of-day" indexing _requires_ a start and an end time. `"T04:00:00"` will never work (the leading zero is also important to remember). C) You set the `origin="2013-03-30 00:00"`, when it's normally `"1970-01-01"`. Set it correctly, and the merge works: `as.POSIXct(1333065600, origin="1970-01-01")+seq(0, 60*60*24-1, by=60)`.

Comment: Indeed it does! I thought I had done the "ct" with the origin at the correct point, but it seems I did not. Problem resolved (until the next one haha) THANKS!